# Finding the minimum value of an array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop

I am making a program that is finding out how many n shaped polygons on an xy plane can be intersected by a line that is parallel to the y axis, I found out that I can just consider the polygons as a line on the x axis with limits from the smallest value of x to the largest value of x. My problem here is, the coordinates can go as far as 10^5 and I am having trouble finding out the minimum value of x for each polygons. I have checked and I think It's already correctm but it always prints out that the minimum value of x is 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long long bangun, sisi, i, j, k, l, count=0, c1=0, countmax=0, bs;
    long long max=0;
    double x;
    long long arrx[1009][1009]={0}, arrxmax[1000]={0}, arrxmin[1000]={10000000};
    scanf("%d", &bangun);
    for(i=0;i<bangun;i++){
        scanf("%d", &sisi);
        for(j=0;j<sisi;j++){
        scanf("%lld", &arrx[i][j]);
        scanf("%d", &bs);
        }
    }
    //give value to arrxmax[i] & arrxmin[i] for polygon i
    for(i=0;i<bangun;i++){
        for(j=0;j<sisi;j++){
            if(arrx[i][j] > arrxmax[i]){
                arrxmax[i] = arrx[i][j];
            }
            //this is the part to find the minimum value
            if(arrxmin[i] > arrx[i][j]){
                arrxmin[i] = arrx[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", arrxmin[0]);
    //finding the largest x of all polygons
    for(i=0;i<bangun;i++){
        if(arrxmax[i]>max){
            max = arrxmax[i];
        }
    }
    for(x=0;x<=max;x+=0.3){
        count = 0;
        for(i=0;i<bangun;i++){
            if(x<arrxmax[i] && x>arrxmin[i]){
                count++;
                c1 = count;
            }
            if(c1>countmax){
                countmax = c1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", countmax);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the input you're using to test this? What output do you expect from that input? Have you considered stepping through in the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: Regardless of the algorithm, you seem to be using too much stack space (>8MB). Unless the stack was explicitly configured to such sizes, you should revert to dynamic memory allocations or expect memory corruptions and crashes

Comment: @RetiredNinja 1
3 21500 500 23500 500 22500 3000, I expected 21500 since it's the smallest, but I got 0 as the smallest. 0 here is not the output of the program, but the output when I want to print arrxmin[0]

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername For now, this is all I can do because I'm still not very far in programming

Comment: I don't want to be blunt, but this approach isn't acceptable. Without fixing the issue I mentioned, there is no point in fixing the algorithm